# Select run-time library in Windows CE AppBuilder for Compact 2013

Tags: windows-ce, windows-embedded-compact

When you install your SDK (let's say the CEPC SDK) you get a folder tree at SdkRootPath. This tree contains two folders with the static libraries:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows CE Tools\SDKs\CEPC\Sdk\Crt\Lib\x86
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows CE Tools\SDKs\CEPC\Sdk\Lib\x86\retail
```

You find a `MSVCRT.lib` in both folders. The default search path order is

1. $(SdkRootPath)crt\Lib\x86
2. $(SdkRootPath)atlmfc\lib\x86
3. $(SdkRootPath)Lib\x86\debug
4. $(SdkRootPath)Lib\x86\retail

What is the purpose of having two *different* copies of the libraries here?
 
What is the best practise to choose the right library?

*Edit*:
The files are of different sizes. The sizes are (in the order mentioned above):

- `Crt\Lib\x86\msvcrt.lib` 2,656,238 Bytes
- `Lib\x86\retail\msvcrt.lib` 1,717,936 Bytes

Comment: Could you give us the file size and date of the MSVCRT.lib files?